# Custom function that returns the latest value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I am trying to create a script using mongo shell in Robo3T, where I can get returned all the latest dates of users that have submitted to userhistories. Although for some reason this script wont work. I am trying to compare 2 rows and then print the date if the ID is the same.

```
function lastDate(userID) {
  print(db.userhistories.find({"user": userID}).sort({date:1}).limit(1));
}

lastDate(db.users.find().forEach(function(val){ val._id.toString()}));
```

What is wrong with this script? Or is there a better way to fix this issue??

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve here or I may be missing something. So you want to query the `userhistories` collection for latest dates for each user?

Comment: Did you mean to call the function in a loop like `db.users.find().forEach(function(val){ lastDate(val._id.toString()) }));`?